# PHP project in htdocs(XAMPP) won't run unless server is started with "php -S localhost:8000"

Tags: php, xampp

So I've a PHP project. I'm using XAMPP for localhost. Usually I keep my project inside htdocs directory, and access the website via "localhost/myProject."

But with this project I've created views manually for routing urls. In root directory I have a file called index.php which is used for routing urls.

```
<?php

$path = trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');
parse_url($path, PHP_URL_PATH);

print_r($path);


$routes = [

    '' => 'views/index.php',
    'about-us' => 'views/about-us.php',
    'admin-login' => 'views/admin_login.html',
    'admin-dashboard' => 'views/adminDashboard.html'


];
if (array_key_exists($path,$routes)) {
    require $routes[$path];
}else {
    require 'views/404-Not-Found.php';
}


?>
```

Now if i want to access my newly created website, I have to run "localhost:8000" in browser and then go to different pages.
I can't access the website like usual(localhost/myProject).
Does it have to do something with .htaccess file?
If so can someone tell me how to work with it?
if not htaccess what might be the issue?
I'm including a image of my file structure.

[image: current working directory and files]

Comment: Welcome Fahim. I hope the code you provided is in index.php. What is the issue which you get when you go to the localhost/myproject?

Comment: doesn't forward to the urls like admin-login
i've narrowed down  the problem to .htaccess file.
I've written one but it the css doesn't show up.

and yes it is in php